# Execute 2 sqlite Queries IOS

Tags: ios7, sqlite

How to execute 2 Sql queries in one method in iOS.Suppose if the second query needs to be performed on the basis of first queries result? How to achieve this? I tried '`Union`',but not able to achieve what is needed?

```
+(void)deleteData{
NSString * docDBPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Documents/audiocall2.db"];
sqlite3 * db;
int status;
status = sqlite3_open([docDBPath UTF8String], &db);
if(  status != SQLITE_OK)
{
     NSLog(@"Error opening DB Code : %d",status);
}
const char *sql="SELECT * FROM  callhistory  GROUP BY number ORDER BY id DESC";
sqlite3_stmt * stmt  = NULL;
status = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
if(status != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"Error preparing sql %d",status);
}
//    if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE)
//    {
//
//    }

while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
{

    NSData *image_data=[NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(stmt,6) length:length];
    NSLog(@"Name : %@  Phone : %d :%@ :start %@:end %@:bool %@",name,uniqueid,number,starttime,endtime,connected);
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_close(db);
```

I need to execute another query which is based on first query

second query.

```
Const char *sql  DELETE FROM callhistory  WHERE id<'2';
```

Comment: why don t you make another function with second query and add this funtion to first function?

Comment: but 2nd query has to work on the results of first query.do u think calling another method works?please share some thoughts.

Comment: i think you should return some kind of data like array from first function.. and then in response to that array delete array items. got my point?